# How to specify a certain csv in the errorbar line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot with three different csvs. In 2 of them, the columns are the same i.e. Year, GMSL and GMSLerror.

In the Frederikse file the columns are Year, GMSL, GMSLerrorlow and GMSLerrorup. How can I tell R to plot the Frederikse error using the columns GMSLerrorlow and GMSLerrorup? I tried the following but it did not work. Thanks.

`````
p1<-files <- c("Frederikse.csv", "ChurchandWhite.csv","Hay.csv")
map_dfr(files, ~ read_csv(.x) %>% 
          mutate(Author = .x)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = GMSL, color = Author,fill=Author)) +
  geom_line(size=0.6)+
  theme_bw(12)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  labs(x = "Year", y = "GMSL (mm)",color="Author")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=GMSL-GMSLerror, ymax =GMSL+GMSLerror,alpha=Author))+
  geom_errorbar("Frederikse.csv",(aes(ymin=GMSL-GMSLerrorlow, ymax =GMSL+GMSLerrorup,alpha=Author)))
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.8))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#BAB3F0","#1D3E72","#201641"))
  
p1


structure(list(Year = 1900:1905, GMSLerrorlow = c(-203.5572666, 
-201.0185091, -212.0740442, -202.6975639, -200.1670151, -192.1312551
), GMSL = c(-173.2614421, -168.8016753, -180.389967, -170.2678322, 
-168.7200709, -160.9814287), GMSLerrorup = c(-141.002807, -135.8976091, 
-148.213824, -138.9305182, -137.4501224, -130.3514508)), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")

structure(list(Time = 1900:1905, GMSL = c(-131.15, -130.5, -129.77, 
-128.85, -128.1, -127.56), GMSLerror = c(25.32, 25.17, 25.01, 
24.86, 24.7, 24.55)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")


structure(list(Time = c(1880.0417, 1880.125, 1880.2083, 1880.2917, 
1880.375, 1880.4583), GMSL = c(-183, -171.1, -164.3, -158.2, 
-158.7, -159.6), GMSLerror = c(24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 24.2, 
24.2)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")````
`````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `mutate` to make `GMSLerrorlow` column for all datasets

```
p1<-files <- c("Frederikse.csv", "ChurchandWhite.csv","Hay.csv")

set_names(files) %>% # give names - can use str_remove to drop `.csv` from names

map_dfr( ~ read_csv(.x), .id = "Author") %>% #use .id argument
mutate(
   GMSLerrorlow = if_else(Author != "Frederikse.csv", GMSLerror, GMSLerrorlow),
   GMSLerrorup = if_else(Author != "Frederikse.csv", GMSLerror, GMSLerrorup)
) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = GMSL, color = Author,fill=Author)) +
  geom_line(size=0.6)+
  theme_bw(12)+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  labs(x = "Year", y = "GMSL (mm)",color="Author")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=GMSL-GMSLerrorlow, ymax =GMSL+GMSLerrorup,alpha=Author))+
  scale_alpha_manual(values = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.8))+
  scale_colour_manual(values=c("#BAB3F0","#1D3E72","#201641"))
```